# R pivot to wide and back to long (multiple groups)

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been using wide table format to create a migration variable (year, municipality -> year, municipality, move) and was wondering if I can flip it back into long table format. However, I now 2 groups per year instead of one. I looked through the existing posts on SO, but couldn't find anything similar.

Here's what I have done:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

# sample data
mydata <- data.frame(id = sort(rep(1:10,3)),
                     year = rep(seq(2009,2011),10),
                     municip = sample(c(NA,1:3),30,replace=TRUE))
```

The data looks like this:

| id | year | municip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2009 | 2 |
| 1 | 2010 | 1 |
| 1 | 2011 | 3 |
| 2 | 2009 | 1 |
| 2 | 2010 | 1 |
| 2 | 2011 | 3 |
| 3 | 2009 | NA |
| 3 | 2010 | NA |
| 3 | 2011 | NA |

```
# turn sideways
mydata.wide <- mydata %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year,
              names_prefix = "municip.",
              values_from = municip)
```

Now it looks like this:

| id | municip.2009 | municip.2010 | municip.2011 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | NA | NA | NA |
| 4 | 1 | NA | 3 |
| 5 | 1 | NA | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 | NA | 3 |
| 8 | 3 | NA | 3 |
| 9 | NA | 1 | NA |
| 10 | 1 | NA | 2 |

Then I'm adding a migration variable (in reality this is done for 12 years):

```
# create migration variable
for (i in 2009:2010){
  
  text.string <- paste0("mydata.wide <- mydata.wide %>%
          mutate(move.",i+1," = case_when(
            is.na(municip.",i,") & is.na(municip.",i+1,") ~ \"NA\",
            is.na(municip.",i,") & !is.na(municip.",i+1,") ~ \"1\",
            !is.na(municip.",i,") & !is.na(municip.",i+1,") 
               & municip.",i," != municip.",i+1," ~ \"3\",
            !is.na(municip.",i,") & is.na(municip.",i+1,") ~ \"4\",   
            TRUE ~ \"2\"
          ))")
  
  eval(parse_expr(text.string))                        
}

# NA: missing in both cases
# 1: move into region
# 2: stayed in region
# 3: moved within region
# 4: moved out of region
```

Now the table looks like this:

| id | municip.2009 | municip.2010 | municip.2011 | move.2010 | move.2011 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 4 | 1 | NA | 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | NA | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 | NA | 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 8 | 3 | NA | 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 9 | NA | 1 | NA | 1 | 4 |
| 10 | 1 | NA | 2 | 4 | 1 |

What I want to do is to flip it back to create something like this:

| id | year | municip | move |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2009 | 2 | NA |
| 1 | 2010 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2011 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 2009 | 1 | NA |
| 2 | 2010 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2011 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 2009 | NA | NA |
| 3 | 2010 | NA | NA |
| 3 | 2011 | NA | NA |

I'm not sure if this can be done with just `pivot_longer` on it's own. I tried a couple of variations. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```r
df <- tribble(~id, ~municip.2009, ~municip.2010, ~municip.2011, ~move.2010, ~move.2011,
1,  2,  1,  3,  3,  3,
2,  1,  1,  3,  2,  3,
3,  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
4,  1,  NA, 3,  4,  1,
5,  1,  NA, 2,  4,  1,
6,  3,  2,  2,  3,  2,
7,  2,  NA, 3,  4,  1,
8,  3,  NA, 3,  4,  1,
9,  NA, 1,  NA, 1,  4,
10, 1,  NA, 2,  4,  1
)


df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -1, names_to = "temp1", values_to = "count") %>% 
  separate(col = temp1, c("temp2", "year")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = temp2, values_from = count)
```

`pivot_longer` collects `municip` and `move` in the same column; with `separate` split `municip` and `move` by the `years`; finally with `pivot_wider` you get the final result.

Comment: Nice one, I like it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think sideways, think longways!

Now, I cannot answer your question completly, because I don't really understand what you are calculating. Is it some sort of factor (1-4)? But I believe you can finish this yourself. Consider the following:

```
> mydata %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(last_year = lag(municip)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  arrange(id) %>% as.data.frame # ignore this line, it is simply for the pleasure of seeing the data.frame
   id year municip last_year
1   1 2009       3        NA
2   1 2010       2         3
3   1 2011      NA         2
4   2 2009      NA        NA
5   2 2010      NA        NA
6   2 2011       1        NA
7   3 2009       3        NA
8   3 2010       2         3
9   3 2011       2         2
10  4 2009       2        NA
11  4 2010      NA         2
12  4 2011       1        NA
13  5 2009       3        NA
14  5 2010      NA         3
15  5 2011       2        NA
16  6 2009       1        NA
17  6 2010       3         1
18  6 2011       2         3
19  7 2009       3        NA
20  7 2010       2         3
21  7 2011       2         2
22  8 2009      NA        NA
23  8 2010      NA        NA
24  8 2011       3        NA
25  9 2009       1        NA
26  9 2010      NA         1
27  9 2011       1        NA
28 10 2009       3        NA
29 10 2010      NA         3
30 10 2011      NA        NA
```

You see? In long-form, you now can simply continue with

```
%>% mutate(move = case_when(
  is.na(.$municip) & is.na(.$last_year) ~ \"NA\",
  # etc.
  ))
```

Did you want the comparision from year i to the following year? Use the function `lead` instead of `lag`.

Lastly, your text-code might not work; when using `case_when` you have to refer to variables in the piped result with `.$`.

Comment: @MrGrumble This would have been my approach when working with a database (because flipping is such a pain then). I'll test both versions and check which ones I like more!

Comment: @MrGrumble in the real data the municiaplities are 3 digit codes, e.g. '091' - yes, categorical (although they don't have to be for this example)

Comment: I now remember why I didn't go that way - I would have to pad out the missing years first. The registry only contains years that people were in, so I would have to pad out the missing years first - I guess `complete(year)` after the `group_by` might work...

Comment: Unfortunately, that takes 2 hours to run (on the full dataset) and then crashes RStudio - sniff.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Aside from getting a faster/bigger computer, you could consider breaking your data into smaller blocks, only loading those small chunks (e.g. per id or municipal) and then handle those. You have unfortunately stumbled upon the woes of handling large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
mydata.wide %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -id,
    names_pattern = "([a-z]+?)\\.(\\d+)", 
    names_to = c("name", "year"),
    values_to = "val",
    values_transform = list(val = as.character)
    ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = name,
    values_from = val
  ) %>% 
  print(n=30)
```

```
 A tibble: 30 × 4
      id year  municip move 
   <int> <chr> <chr>   <chr>
 1     1 2009  2       NA   
 2     1 2010  3       3    
 3     1 2011  NA      4    
 4     2 2009  2       NA   
 5     2 2010  NA      4    
 6     2 2011  2       1    
 7     3 2009  1       NA   
 8     3 2010  2       3    
 9     3 2011  1       3    
10     4 2009  NA      NA   
11     4 2010  NA      NA   
12     4 2011  1       1    
13     5 2009  NA      NA   
14     5 2010  2       1    
15     5 2011  3       3    
16     6 2009  3       NA   
17     6 2010  3       2    
18     6 2011  3       2    
19     7 2009  NA      NA   
20     7 2010  NA      NA   
21     7 2011  NA      NA   
22     8 2009  NA      NA   
23     8 2010  2       1    
24     8 2011  NA      4    
25     9 2009  3       NA   
26     9 2010  2       3    
27     9 2011  NA      4    
28    10 2009  2       NA   
29    10 2010  3       3    
30    10 2011  1       3
```

Comment: also a very nice solution!

Comment: the regex is perhaps a bit of an overkill, `names_sep` would suffice